# Pytest imitate ID

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Use the **sqlalchemy** and I need to write test using **pytest**

**example:**

```
def test_update_user():
    user_id = 2


    user_query = session.query(User). \
        filter(User.id == user_id)


    user = user_query. \
        order_by(User.id.desc()). \
        first()

    user_query.update({'first_name': 'Bob', 'last_name': 'Marley'})
    session.commit()

    assert user.id == user_id
```

How I can imitate ID Without an explicit assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want your assert to be about user.id ? Shouldn't you read `user` again and check if its first & last name have been updated ?

Anyway, I don't think you can really imitate ID but you can use a Regex to check if it has the right format.

Comment: Using **assert** here because I need check whether object correct updated with ID which was chosen

Comment: Actually I don't get your code, so let me comment it and tell me if I'm wrong somewhere :  

 `user_query = session.query(User). \
        filter(User.id == APP_ID)`  
This get you one (or zero) user, with an id equals to APP_ID (which is ?)  
`user = user_query. \
        order_by(User.id.desc()). \
        first()`  
I don't get the point of this ?

Comment: No, all this things works fine, but I need imitate user_id, i don't wanna do explicit assignment for **user_id**

Comment: But what do you mean by "imitate" ? If your id is a simple int (like in your code), and you just want one randomly, you can do : user_id = random.randint(0, id_max) (id_max being the number of user you have - 1)

Comment: Yes, it's my mistake, thanks for hint. It's works for me